# How to continually update a HashMap where both Key and Value are ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am working on a project that involves minor combining and relating of datasets for some work, and have been stuck for some time.

I have groups of data, which are similar to other groups of data in a project. I have an array list of the group's names. I am comparing these similar groups to other dataset, describing similar things. (A collection of groups, which are similar to other groups in their own collection).

I've been trying to solve this by using:

```
HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>
```

It is proving very difficult to add another group (by name, a String) when another relation is found.

If I find another group from each dataset and want to add to a current ArrayList (which is why I am using ArrayLists), it creates another entry, where the new key and value are the same as the previous but with the added element in each ArrayList.

Here is the current, relevant code:

```
... 
for(ArrayList<String> similarGroupsDataset : map.keySet()) {
    ...
        ArrayList<String> value = map.get(similarGroupsDataset);
        ArrayList<String> key = similarGroups;
        value.add(groupToAdd);
        key.add(groupToAdd2);
        map.remove(similarGroupsDataset);
        map.put(key, value);
}
```

Store the ArrayList key and Arraylist value into variables, add the newly found pieces of data, remove the old entry, and add the updated version.

For some reason this seams to not remove the entry which does not have the newly added found data.

So if I print out the map, it would look like
({1,2},{a,b}) , ({1,2,3},{a,b,c})
What it should look like is
({1,2,3} , {a,b,c}), taking out the irrelevant entry.
Where 1,2 in dataset1 are similar, which are similar still to a,b from dataset2, etc. if that makes sense.

I have tried to do

```
map.get(relevantGroupFromDataset2).add(data) 
//adds the newly found similar group to the list of groups 
//which are all similar to eachother, from dataset1.
```

That works sometimes, but only for the value, not the key, it seems.

In the end, my goal is to remake these datasets with an identifier tying these groups together by a new identifier, rather than their current identifier which doesn't tie them together in the way I want.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better data structure to use in this scenario? Is a HashMap or similar structure the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

> If I find another group from each dataset and want to add to a current
>   ArrayList (which is why I am using ArrayLists), it creates another
>   entry, where the new key and value are the same as the previous but
>   with the added element in each ArrayList.

You use as key an ArrayList.
In a map, the keys are retrieved from their `hashCode()/equals()` method.
So when you change the content of the ArrayList key here :

```
ArrayList<String> value = map.get(similarGroupsDataset);
ArrayList<String> key = similarGroups;
value.add(groupToAdd);
key.add(groupToAdd2); // <-- here
```

`hashCode()` and `equals()` will not produce the same result any longer. 
It is considered as a new key for the map.

So  `map.put(key, value);` will add a new element.

---

It is not obvious to give you a good workaround with your actual code as the logic performed by the Map and what you expect is really not clear.
For example :

```
value.add(groupToAdd);
key.add(groupToAdd2);
```

is either a very bad naming or you populate only with groups the key-values of your map.

The general idea is you should not use in your map a key which the `hashCode()/ equals()` result may change after that the key were added in the map.
To achieve it :

- Either put the value with the the ArrayList key at a time where you  know that the key  will not be modified any longer.
- Either remove the value with the key and add it again with the new key.

In any case, to avoid this kind of errors, you should create an unmodifiable List for keys and pass it in the map:

```
map.put(Collections.unmodifiableList(keys), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

By `key.add(groupToAdd2);` the *key* is changed, but keys of a map must be effective immutable:

> [Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Swap the lines `key.add(groupToAdd2);` and `map.remove(similarGroupsDataset);` to fix this or even better:

```
...
for (Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    ... 
        map.remove(entry.getKey()); // remove from map before changing the key
        entry.getKey().add(groupToAdd2);
        entry.getValue().add(groupToAdd);
        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Map one should better keep the key object immutable.
When one changes the key object in a HashMap, and the new hashCode is different, the map is corrupt.

So you have to remove the old key object and insert the new key object.

The data structure fitting your example would be a tree of (group, datum), where you extend the path to the leafs.

```
tree -> (a, 1)
            +--> (x, 24)
            +--> (b, 2)
                      +--> (c, 3)
```

And consider only all paths to a final leaf.

Admittedly a bit more work.